# Alert when approaching 2-million cell limit in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, limit, alert

It's important to know when my Google Sheets approaches 2-million cells because when it passes the limit, paid orders stop arriving without notice. This irritates my customers.

Is there a way to calculate how many cells I have used so that when the number exceeds, say, 1700000, I can take some kind of manual action?

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a single sheet, Use Conditional formatting:

```
       COUNTA(A:Z)+COUNTBLANK(A:Z)>=1700000
```

Otherwise, Use COUNTA + COUNTBLANKS on all other sheets and import them to get a full count.

You could also use scripts. Here's one: https://www.sheetgo.com/google-sheets-2-million-cells-limit/

Answer (score 1):

How about this method? If you have some sheets in a Spreadsheet, I propose the use of Google Apps Script. I think that this is one of some methods.

2,000,000 which is the limitation of cell number is the total cell number of all sheets in a Spreadsheet. And the empty cells are included in the number.

The script reflected this is as follows.

#### Script :

```
var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
var count = 0;
for (var i in sheets) {
  count += sheets[i].getMaxRows() * sheets[i].getMaxColumns();
}
if (count > 1700000) {
  // do something
}
```

If you want to retrieve the number of cells in various Spreadsheets using this script, please modify from `var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();` to `var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId).getSheets();`.